# Does a compound key in EF work?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, testing

I started using EF 4.1 code first.

I have a entity table like this:

```
public AMapping()
{
   Property(x => x.Counter).IsRequired();
   HasKey(x => x.AID);
   HasKey(x => x.BID);

   HasRequired<A>(x => x.A)
      .WithMany(y => y.CList)
      .HasForeignKey(f => f.AID);

   ToTable("A");
}
```

Table A column look something like this:

```
  AID(PK, FK, int, not null)
  Counter(int, not null)
  BID(PK, FK, int, not null)
```

While writing save integration test it is giving following error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'BID', table 'Sprint3.dbo.A';
>   column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

But I can see that I'm passing an integer value.

Is there any constraint about composite primary keys in EF 4.1 code first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
HasKey(x => new { x.AID, x.BID});
```

Never used it, just saw it in the docs yesterday :)